# ErrorMessage":"Insufficient Lake Formation permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lake-formation

I was trying to edit schema from AWS Glue console.

I am getting following error while trying to save my changes.

```
{"service":"AWSGlue","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"AccessDeniedException","requestId":"644bfcb2-75a8-456b-b17a-e22e829345d2","errorMessage":"Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s): Required Alter on recidivism_clustering_model_output_csv","type":"AwsServiceError"}
```

I have provided necessary access to the s3 buckets and tables in glue using Lakeformation.

Can anyone tell me what the best way to edit schema via glue?

And wny am i getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually add my user as a database owner to the database resource. Not sure why this sometimes happens. My role is a datalake administrator but for some reason that did not work if I added my role as a Database admin then I could alter the database.

There is probably something else going on but I could not find it.